# Why does the glm() function in R give an error message when trying to fit a step function using cut()?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, cross-validation

I am working with Wage data in library ISLR. Wage includes wage and age as columns.

Why does cv.glm throw an Error for the script below that disappears when test.fit.12.1 is replaced by test.fit.12? Also, summary(test.fit.12.1) shows the same levels as Wage$tmp.

```
- Wage$tmp <- cut(Wage$age,12)
- #test.fit.12 = glm(wage~tmp, data = Wage)
- test.fit.12.1 = glm(wage~cut(age,12), data = Wage)
- test = cv.glm(Wage ,test.fit.12.1)$delta[1]
```

```
Error message: Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action =
na.action, xlev = object$xlevels): factor cut(age, 12) has new level (32.995,33]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you run `cv.glm`, the data are split into parts, with a model fitted to one part and predictions calculated on the other part. The fit and predict steps both call `cut` and the cutpoints will typically be different. That means the levels of the factor `cut(age,12)` will be different in the fitting data and the prediction data. R is warning you that the levels of the factor are different, so the prediction would be meaningless

The default for `cv.glm` is leave-one-out cross-validation, so the prediction step is trying to run `cut(age,12)` on a single observation!

The way around this is to create the variable ahead of time, as in your commented-out line